# How to make the Cake-build's Example project work on Docker

Tags: docker, mono, cakebuild

I am trying to use Docker with the [Cake build automation system](https://cakebuild.net/) with no success.

I am starting running the mono image:

```
docker run -it mono:latest
```

Then I install git:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install git
```

Then I clone the Cake's example project:

```
git clone https://github.com/cake-build/example.git
cd example/
```

Then I run the build script:

```
./build.sh
```

The result is:

```
Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Restoring NuGet package Cake.0.23.0.
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
Got a bad hardware address length for an AF_PACKET 16 8
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/cake/0.23.0/cake.0.23.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/cake/0.23.0/cake.0.23.0.nupkg 589ms
Installing Cake 0.23.0.
Could not restore NuGet packages.
...
```

What could I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That issue was solved some months ago on https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/5159

And since the cake example is old, I'd recommend creating an example with the latest version of mono